# using a spring session bean for logging

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, aop, spring-aop

I have a Spring web app.
I would like to change its logging behavior to always prepend log lines with the name of the logged in user which is stored in a session-scoped bean.
We are using log4j.
There is a lot of classes which are logging but are not Spring-managed.
While we do use some AOP, it is all Spring AOP, not AspectJ, so I can't modify log4j behavior globally (and introducing AspectJ just for a silly logging improvement doesn't sound like a good idea).

I can't think of any sane (or even acceptable insane) way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your servlet, you could use the nested diagnostic context of log4j do to so:

```
NDC.push(getUsername());
try {
    ....
}
finally {
    NDC.pop();
}
```

If you are using the spring dispatcher servlet, you could wrap the dispatcher servlet in your own servlet, delegate all calls to the dispatcher servlet and add the NDC-stuff there.

Comment: If I were you I would use MDC (then you can have more properties, e.g. in a log4j format, "user=%X{user}, path=%X{path}").  And I wouldn't write a new servlet - use a Filter.

Comment: @DaveSyer yeah, MDC probably sounds better.  I don't want to screw with tomcat filters though, so I would probably use Spring AOP to set it.

Comment: Tomcat?  Filter is part of the servlet spec, so not specific to the container (and they are very easy to write).

Comment: They are easy to write but [I suspect] introduce a deployment/configuration action which I don't like.